# Proper way to start a background process

Tags: background-process, daemon, disown

I am just trying to start up a basic node.js server on a remote machine in a ssh session. This seems to work:

```
nohup node server/server.js &  disown
```

Maybe I don't need nohup? what's the "official" way to startup a background process that's not going to get killed by SIGTERM etc? I just want to start a background process then exit the session and have the process continue to run.

Comment: Neither `nohup` nor `disown` will do anything related to the `TERM` signal, only the `HUP` signal (`nohup` makes it ignore it and `disown` stops the shell form sending it, so using both is not needed).  Could you expand on the "etc." at the end?

Comment: sure, I just want to start a background process then exit the session and have the process continue to run

Comment: Have you considered using either `tmux` or GNU `screen`?

Comment: ... or creating a proper system service?

Comment: isn't a proper system service just using these types of facilities under the hood? can you add an answer showing one or the other?

Comment: There's no "proper" way to do that. Depending on how your _Linux_ system is configured, `systemd` may still kill your background process, despite the `nohup`, `setsid`, etc. Since `systemd` is not yet a standard (thank God!), there's no standard way to prevent it from doing that, either in general, or for a particular process.

Answer (score 4):

`screen` and `tmux` certainly work but they are geared towards interactive sessions (often on remote computers) you want to disconnect and reconnect to. Since your application seems to be a server of some sort I would suggest to run it as a system service (often called "[daemon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_(computing))") instead.

In the following I'm assuming you're using a system using [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd). All you need to do is create a unit file in `/etc/systemd/system/foo.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=My foo service
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/node /absolute/path/to/your/server.js
Restart=always
User=nobody

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Modify the user as needed if your service needs to access files on your disk. Once the service file is in place run the following commands to ask systemd to reload its configuration files and run your service:

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
$ sudo systemctl start foo.service
```

You want to start it automatically during system start? Just enable it and you're all set:

```
$ sudo systemctl enable foo.service
```

---

Running into problems? You can troubleshoot with the following commands:

```
$ systemctl status foo.service
$ journalctl -u foo.service
```

---

Regarding your requirement about preventing the service from being terminated/killed: I would say that's very difficult at the least. Even if your users don't have permission to kill your application your system might run out of RAM and the out-of-memory killer might decide to kill your service since it happens to be the one which is using RAM most aggressively. My suggestion would be to go with the `Restart=always` included in the above example instead which ensures systemd restarts the service when it crashes/exits.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the screen command to save terminal sessions that can be accessed at a later time. This keeps you from having to kill processes that may be attached to a terminal session. So one example of how this is useful is if you were going to start a huge data transfer. You can start a screen session, start transferring the data, go home and ssh back into your work machine, and access the screen session without the transfer being interrupted

To install it:

`sudo apt install screen`  for Ubuntu or Ubuntu variant

`yum install screen` Redhat or Redhat variant

you can then run

`screen -S <screen name>` to create new screen session

`screen -ls` list screen sessions

`screen -r <screen name>` attach to specific screen.

tmux is slowly replacing the screen command so I would recommend looking into that as well.

Comment: yes I hear `tmux` can also be used for this, is that the best option?

Comment: Yeah, I would just go with learning tmux. @AlexanderMills

Answer (score 1):

Just to add the simplest/obvious answer, for completeness & posterity (only difference here is [closing `stdin`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19955260/what-is-dev-null-in-bash/19955475#19955475), otherwise it's the same as the example in the question, including [redirect stdout/stdin](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) syntax):

(1) If you don't care about stderr & stdout:

```
$ nohup {prog} </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

(2) If you want to log stderr & stdout,

```
$ nohup {prog} </dev/null >/path/to/out.log 2>&1 &
```

(3) If you want to log stderr & stdout to separate files,

```
$ nohup {prog} </dev/null >/path/to/out.log 2>/path/to/err.log &
```

Rotate logs if you want to keep 'em; these examples will overwrite at every startup. Optionally name logs with a date, e.g., `out-$(date '+%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S').log` Once you start going down that path,however, it's better to configure a service, as the other answers indicate, to let the system do the work for you. I do like `screen` / `tmux`, but only if I'm debugging a process that I want to actually reconnect the terminal eventually. Otherwise, I prefer background processes & logging.

Comment: yeah this is more of what I am looking for

Comment: so I guess closing `stdin` was the main thing I was missing in the OP?

Comment: It's "correct" in the canonical sense, but often unnecessary. I notice that gnu nohup does this automatically anyway, but if on a non-Linux system, depending on how the process is written, results could vary (example: running ‘ssh host command‘ across many targets could be an example where you don't know/care about the OS) http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/nohup-invocation.html.